# $\int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x)\,dx=0\overset{?}{\Rightarrow}\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int\limits_0^x f(z)\,dz =
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\int\limits_0^x f(z)\,dz}{x}= \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(x\int\limits_0^x f(z)\,dz\right)'}{x'}= \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\int\limits_0^x f(z)\,dz+xf(x)\right)= \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=0$$
But this is true only if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\int\limits_0^x f(z)\,dz=\infty$.

So how can we prove or refute that $\int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x)\,dx=0\Rightarrow\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=0$?

Comment: Depending on your constraints on $f$, this could be false. What kind of function are you requiring $f$ to be?

Comment: This is false. In fact, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ is false. *If* you know that the limit exists, then it is indeed zero. But the existence of the limit is not automatic.

Comment: No, the issue is not on the numerator. In fact, we do not need the numerator to tend to infinity to apply l'Hôpital's rule here. The issue is that $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)$ may fail to exist, and as pointed out, in fact $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ may fail to exist.

Comment: @Cameron Williams $f(x)$ is simply a continuous function.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo I know that $\int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x)\,dx=0$. I want to prove or refute that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=0$.

Comment: @Constructor Yes. I am aware. I mentioned this in the first comment; in the second comment I pointed out a different issue with your sketch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \int_0^\infty \sin(x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}} $$

So if you just subtract off anything else with integral $\sqrt{\pi/8}$ that vanishes at infinity, you get a counterexample.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Thank you.

Comment: I must be dense, but in what universe is the integral of the lhs even defined?

Comment: @Igor: It's an ordinary, improper Riemann integral. What is surprising about it? That the integrand doesn't converge to zero? The relevant point to note is that it's the *area* under the graph not matters, not the height. The graph if $\sin(x^2)$ consists of regions alternating between above and below the $x$-axis: adding up their areas gives an alternating sum whose terms converge to zero.